# Newer CSS not recognized by VSCode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

VSCode will produce a squiggly line under CSS it does not recognize.
For example:

```
justify-self: start;
```

Naming grid lines is not recognized. The `[col]` gives it problems.
For example:

```
 grid-template-columns:  repeat(6, [col] 150px);
```

I've tried installing a number of different CSS extensions in an attempt to correct the issue but none of them have worked.
For the record, I'm **not** using the nightly version of VSCode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you really depending on the IDE / Editor for Code Linting? Seriously, that shouldn't be an issue mate!

Comment: Not using it for linting at all actually. It's just annoying.. Really, really annoying.

Comment: @PraveenKumar how is the JS intellisense for Sublime, or Atom if you have experience with it?

Comment: Been using Sublime for long time and I have no regrets. Intellisense isn't there. But there's some suggestions coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use css validation of properties you can change `settings.json`:

```
"css.lint.unknownProperties": "ignore"
```

This will no longer highlight:

```
justify-self: start;
```

AND won't work for all remaining unknown properties:

```
gibberish: wow;
```

Comment: Thanks, seems this is the best option for now. I'm going to download the VSCode insiders addition and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 22):

Having looked for similar recently whilst trying to get VS Code to ignore "mso-" css rules for html emails, VS Code now allows you to add valid properties to your user settings for scss or css.

```
"scss.lint.validProperties": [
    "mso-table-lspace",
    "mso-table-rspace",
    "mso-line-height-rule",
    "mso-hide"
],
"css.lint.validProperties": [
    "mso-table-lspace",
    "mso-table-rspace",
    "mso-line-height-rule",
    "mso-hide"
]
```

The location for each OS for the settings.json is provided in this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations).

Comment: I'm not sure why Flapper didn't get a thumbs up for this. This seems to be the most reasonable way to handle this code until VS do something. I would rather qualify what can be passed than ignoring everything.

Answer (score 4):

@Flapper answer is the correct one, since it's possible to configure the specific property to validate or ignore.
With @Alex answer, one can misspell a property and don't receive a warning, because they are all ignored.

Additionally to @Flapper answer I just what to visually show where to change this
configuration at VS Code, instead of editing the file manually:

[image: VS Code]

Comment: Giving such a good guideline was so helpful for clumsy people at config like me. For linux users the settings are under Code>Preferences>Settings

Comment: One picture that describes a click orgie ;) Thx.