# My CSS doesn't recognize the scroll-snap commands

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

I am writing a website in HTML [This is what visual studio tells me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRn8r.png) for school and the CSS file's doesn't recognize my snap-scroll-type tag and my snap-scroll-align tag. I am writing in Atom but because of this problem i tried visual studio and it still doesn't recognizes the tags.
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZpZc.png)

Comment: Is it not working for you, or you are just worried about VScode?!

Comment: Regarding your code: you should avoid using and id multiple times. Ids should be unique. Probably using the class attribute will serve you better here.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a VSCode bug I'd assume, try searching for something within the marketplace such as CSS intellisense.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type
I also don't know if you're utilizing it correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response but unfortunately i could not find the problem in my file and i don't know how to douse it correctly. I have been trying for hours and i am getting pretty sick about it.

Answer (score 0):

There have been multiple questions asked on SO regarding unknown properties in VS Code. You should be able to whitelist valid properties if necessary, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133730/2029959
As pointed out on VS Code's Github repo - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47775#issuecomment-420082168 - it actually shouldn't be an issue anymore as MDN data *should* be linked to. (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48443)

If - on the other hand - your code doesn't work in the browser, please update your question and show us your code or submit a link to see.

Comment: I have added my code to my question. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: That sounds like an IDE issue. If your code works, then you should whitelist scroll-snap-type as mentioned above. As the property is mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) I guess it probably is an issue of either synchronizing the IDE validator or of the property being part of a CSS module which is only in ["Candidate Recommendation" status](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scroll-snap-1/) and not in a final "Recommendation". In other words: just ignore that message and you'll be fine.